# Does PlatformUI.createDisplay() ensure creation of Display object through UI thread?

Tags: java, user-interface, thread-safety, swt, eclipse-rcp

How should I ensure creation of [Display](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html) object through UI Thread only?

Does [PlatformUI](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FPlatformUI.html).createDisplay() ensure creation of Display object through UI thread?

Comment: Are you asking about code in the `IApplication` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlatformUI.createDisplay` basically just does a `new Display()` if the display has not already been created. It is intended to be used in the `IApplication` like this:

```
public class Application implements IApplication
{
  @Override
  public Object start(final IApplicationContext context)
  {
    final Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    try
     {
       final int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
       if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
         return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;

        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
     }
    finally
     {
       display.dispose();
     }
  }
```

which will create the display and run the RCP using the current thread as the user interface thread.

On Mac OS X the `-XstartOnFirstThread` argument is also required to get the correct UI thread.